# what is java:comp/env?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

what is meant by `java:comp/env` ?

What does the look up like :

```
Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

do ?

I understand that a look-up like :

```
(DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDatasource")
```

looks up for the name `MyDatasource` in the `context.xml` or `web.xml` to get the URL of the database. *Is it so ? !!* But what does the former look up do ?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik but that does not answer my question.

Comment: **Please open and read the link before voting to close this question. Dont just go after the title.**

Comment: It sure looks like an answer to me. It's a root namespace provided by the container for you to look up your resources in.

Comment: This is a good question for people trying to migrate from Weblogic to Tomcat for example

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`java:comp/env` is the node in the JNDI tree where you can find properties for the current Java EE component (a webapp, or an EJB).

```
Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

allows defining a variable pointing directly to this node. It allows doing

```
SomeBean s = (SomeBean) envContext.lookup("ejb/someBean");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/dataSource");
```

rather than

```
SomeBean s = (SomeBean) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/someBean");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource");
```

Relative paths instead of absolute paths. That's what it's used for.

Comment: What is _this_ node meant for ? There would be many nodes in the JNDI tree.

Comment: I still don't get the feel of what actually is `java:comp/env`.

Comment: Each JEE component (webapp, EJB) can define properties that are local to this component. And these properties are accessible through `java:comp/env`. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#web.xml_configuration for example. EJBs have the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm far late, but I was asking the same question, and I think I came some answer. So, if I may put my two cents.

`java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource`

- `java:` is just like `jdbc:` from connection string. Acts as a protocol.
- `comp` is the root for all JNDI contexts.
- `env` is the subcontext for all resource related. There is another for user. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19747-01/819-0079/dgjndi.html) out.
- `jdbc` is the subcontext for jdbc resources. There are types. Check the link from the previous bullet.
- `myDataSource` is the name of your jdbc resource.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - clear explanation.

Comment: @joker: The link you shared from Sun Java System Application Server is a very useful source to understand the jargon in JNDI. I can hardly find it in tomcat docs while setting it as it never explained much there. I found the Admin Guide as well in the Sun link, it clears the whole picture. Thanks.

Comment: `comp` is short for "composite", as in `javax.naming.CompositeName`.

Answer (score 10):

It's an in-memory global hashtable where you can store global variables by name.

The "java:" url scheme causes JNDI to look for a `javaURLContextFactory` class, which is usually provided by your app container, e.g. [here is Tomcat's implementation javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/naming/java/javaURLContextFactory.html)

See also [NamingManager.getURLContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/NamingManager.html#getURLContext(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Hashtable))