# JDBC Connection using JNDI : Name Clash?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

Trying to set up a couple of JDBC connections in the context.xml of my tomcat instance but struggling to understand why some names seem to clash.

With some combinations of name I get the folllowing:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.naming.Context

Can someone explain why it doesn't work if I have 2 resources with names like:

```
name="jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/5"
name="jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/5/6"
```

But changing the second name to this does work:

```
name="jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/4/6"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions), *name* is the JNDI name relative to the [java:comp/env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099095/what-does-javacomp-env-do) context. The full name is treated as a path with the elements separated by `/`.

In your example,

```
name="jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/5"
```

creates the data source node `5` under the path

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4
```

The following

```
name="jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/5/6"
```

then tries to create the data source node `6` at path

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/5
```

The exception occurs because Tomcat expects a path element (Context) at `5` but finds a data source instead.

In your working example, you create the data source `6` under the different path

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres/1/2/3/4/6
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I see, I assumed the whole value of _name_ would be used as a key, - clearly not!

Comment: I think my lack of understanding stems from considering this from a DNS perspective, it makes more sense to think in a file system context i.e. a directory and a file with the same name cannot exist at the same path.